# Can not remove NotificationCenter observer inside protocol extension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I created an extended protocol to 'pop up' any view that adopts it. When show is called and the view is shown, an observer to detect that the keyboard will be shown is added to the NotificationCenter. When the view is dismissed, this observer should be removed from the default NotificationCenter.

This is not happening unfortunately. I assume that 'self' is not the observer in this case. I considered saving the observer returned in 'addobserver' to a variable but I don't know how to go about that inside protocols. Any suggestions will very much be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
protocol PopUpProtocol {
    func show()
    func dismiss()

    var dialogHeight:CGFloat {get}
    var backgroundView:UIView {get}
    var dialogView:UIView {get set}
}

extension PopUpProtocol where Self:UIView{
    func show(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil) {_ in
            self.keyboardWillShow()
        }
        self.backgroundView.alpha = 0
        self.dialogView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height , width: self.frame.width, height: self.dialogHeight)

        UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.66
            self.dialogView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height-self.dialogHeight , width: self.frame.width, height: self.dialogHeight)
        })

    }

    func dismiss(){

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = 0
            self.dialogView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height , width: self.frame.width, height: self.dialogHeight)
        }, completion: { (completed) in
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }

    func keyboardWillShow()
    {
        print("Keyboard will come up")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, while I am not able to fully explain the details, I found a solution. I was able to save the observer. The observed was stored as an associated object:

```
var KeyboardShowObserverObjectKey: UInt8 = 1

extension PopUpProtocol where Self:UIView{

var keyboardShowObserverObject: NSObjectProtocol? {
    get {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &KeyboardShowObserverObjectKey) as? NSObjectProtocol
    }
    set {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &KeyboardShowObserverObjectKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }
}
```

When I add the observer, I then set keyBoardShowObserverObject:

```
keyboardShowObserverObject = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        self.keyboardWillShow()
    }
```

When I want to remove the observer, I run this function:

```
private func removeKeyboardObservers() {
    if let keyboardShowObserverObject = keyboardShowObserverObject {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(keyboardShowObserverObject)
    }
    keyboardShowObserverObject = nil
}
```

Furthermore, I needed to declare my protocol as class bound:

```
protocol PopUpProtocol : class {
```

Hopefully this will help anyone struggling with the same.